# Sum list elements when sum is not greater than given interval, else skip element

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list of numbers and I need to get some of these, but:
list element should be skipped if sum + this element is bigger or smaller than given numbers in interval.
I try to do continue within for loop, but smth is wrong and I do not understand what.
How can I do this in correct way?
Thanks in advance

I tried this (sum should start from 1)

```
numbers = [3,2,-3,-1,5,7,-1,-2]
interval = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sum = 1

for i in range(0,len(numbers)):
    sum = sum + numbers[i]
    if sum not in interval:
        continue
    print(sum)
```

So,

```
    1+3+2=6 <- its ok
    6+(-3) = 3 <- its ok
    3+(-1) = 2 <- its ok
    2+ 5 = 7 ok

7+7 = 14 <- thats not ok
```

because 14 is not in interval. So if its not in interval loop should skip 7 value and goes to -1 value.

Comment: "Something is wrong" is hard to judge. What I can tell you, without knowing if this is event remotely close to your problem, is that you're adding the number and *then* end the current iteration, i.e. only skipping the pring but not the unwanted addition. So either check before summing (adjust condition) or subtract in case there's a unwanted sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. But right now you are doing these steps:

- go through each element in numbers
- add next element to sum
- check if sum is in not in interval
- if true continue
- print sum

To me it is usually easier to think the other way, if it is in interval then I want something to happen. As I understood your question is that you want to print these numbers:

```
4 6 3 2 7 6 4
```

This code should do the trick:

```
numbers = [3,2,-3,-1,5,7,-1,-2]
interval = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sum = 1

for i in range(0,len(numbers)):
    if (sum + numbers[i]) in interval:
        sum = sum + numbers[i]
        print(sum)
```

But if you want to do your logic, if would put the adding inside an else like this:

```
numbers2 = [3,2,-3,-1,5,7,-1,-2]
interval2 = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sum2 = 1

for j in range(0,len(numbers2)):
    if sum2 + numbers2[j] not in interval2:
        continue
    else:
        sum2 = sum2 + numbers2[j]
        print(sum2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [3,2,-3,-1,5,7,-1,-2]
interval = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sum = 1

for i in range(0,len(numbers)):
    if sum in interval:
        sum = sum + numbers[i]
        print(sum)
```